# Flux of $\vec F=\left(2\pi x+\frac{2x^2y^2}{\pi} \right) \vec{\imath}+\left(2\pi xy-\frac{4y}{\pi}\right)\vec{\jmath}$ across an ellipse

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

To calculate the flux of the vector field $$\vec F=\left(2\pi x+\frac{2x^2y^2}{\pi} \right) \vec{\imath}+\left(2\pi xy-\frac{4y}{\pi}\right)\vec{\jmath}$$
along the outward normal across the ellipse $x^2+16y^2=4$

I know that to get the normal vector, I have to calculate the gradient of the surface.
$$\hat{n} =   \dfrac{\langle 2x, 32y\rangle}{||\langle 2x, 32y\rangle||}$$
Then,
$$\int_S {F} \cdot \mathbf{n} \ dS $$
can be obtained but its a very tedious calculation.How can I simplify this?Are there any other approaches?

Comment: Try green's  theorem in normal form

Comment: Give your calculations ... Can you explain how tedious it is?

Comment: You can see my question for more details

Comment: It must be zero 'cause the vector field is coplanar with the ellipse